# SMD potentiometer direction

Tags: potentiometer, bidirectional

I currently struggling with a circuit and trying to identify the parts which may cause the problem. The circuit needs a trim potentiometer. Mine looks like [image]

with the symbol

[image]

Does the direction have to be from 1-positive to 3-negative?
Or can I place it on both directions

Comment: it's a potentiometer. It consists of resistive elements. You know very well whether these work the same in both directions. Where's your question coming from?

Comment: May we understand why you believe this will behave differently based on orientation? The only difference I see is mechanical positioning and rotation direction which you wish to adjust your resistance.

Comment: I thought so. It was the only part left which may cause trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it either way and it will function, however you may wish to pick one particular way so that the rotation makes more sense to the user.

The symbols I have created for internal use are marked CCW and CW rather than pin numbers  so it's clear which footprint pin represents each.

For example, if you want Vout to be maximum when the trimpot is fully CW, you would make pin 1 the CW end, and your schematic would reflect that. It's up to you whether you want to show the pin number, I don't think it's helpful.

[image]

Not really relevant for SMD trimpots, but note that if you have a nonlinear or otherwise asymmetrical pot such as an audio taper volume control or a pot with an off-center tap, or a pot with a switch at one end of the travel, there are other reasons to get the CW and CCW orientation correct, as @jsotola points out.

Comment: you are forgetting that orientation makes a difference for anything other than linear taper